# How to select the next node in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

For example if I have this code:

```
<address>
    <type>work</type>
    <value>123 ABC Street </value>
</address>
<address>
    <type>home</type>
    <value>789 XYZ Lane </value>
</address>
```

How could I select the `value` of only the work type address?

I need to look at the type of address and if it's work type grab "123 ABC Street" and set it to a variable.

Comment: Te answer depends on the context - please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have:

```
<adresses>
   <address>
      <type>work</type>
      <value>123 ABC Street </value>
   </address>
   <address>
      <type>home</type>
      <value>789 XYZ Lane </value>
   </address>
</adresses>
```

then:

```
<xsl:template match="adresses">
    <xsl:value-of select="address[type='work']/value"/>
</xsl:template>
```

will return:

```
123 ABC Street
```